# how to call onActivityResult in non Activity class android

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication

I have created Fragment and when click a button get popup like dialog alter view. in that view include google sign in button. when i connect to the firebase and continue the implementation after the **startActivityForResult**  i need to override onActivityResult method. but popup corresponded class extend another Dialog class and can not override onActivityResult method. when going to override it shows *method does not override method from its superclass*  error. how to solve this. and how to implement my firebase login.

thank you. here is my code

```
public class DialogGoogle extends Dialog  { private Activity activity; @BindView(R.id.btn_google)
LinearLayout btnGoogle; private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private int RC_SIGN_IN = 1; public DialogGoogle(Activity a, boolean isTab, int width, int height) {
    super(a, R.style.DialogTheme);
    this.activity = a;
    this.isTab = isTab;
    this.windowWidth = width;
    this.windowHeight = height;}
```

in onCreate method

```
// Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(this.activity.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this.activity,gso);
```

After i created some method

```
public void signInGoogle() {Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);}
```

in after startActivityForResult() I need to get result and i used onActivityResult() but i cannot override method in that DialogGoogle class. i run usually  signInGoogle() method in button click

Comment: Instead of describing your problem, please add the related code to the question.

Comment: I want to override onActivityResult method in normal java class.

Comment: You cannot do that unless you extend `AppCompatActivity`. In that case, it becomes an activity.

Comment: i edit my problem with code part. please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

You start Fragments in a Activity and there you Override the **onActivityResult** method but first you start your auth like in the documentation:

```
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build());
// Create and launch sign-in intent
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build(),
    RC_SIGN_IN);
```

RC_SIGN_IN is a static field and this is the indicator that you can check if the Activity is finished.

Comment: Sir from my fragment button(when click), its open Dialog popup and its popup have google sign in button. that Dialog have another SignInDialog class with extend DialogClass. and all button click function in popup included in SignInDialog class. then I want to implement Google Sign in method from SignInDialog class. but from that SignInDialog class i cannot override onActivityResult method because SignInDialog class is not a activity class. so what i have do? please give me a solution.

Comment: So just to be shure, your app open a dialog and that dialog opens the Google Login dialog right?

Comment: I edit my question with code part. please give a solution